# Captura de imagem para base64

Tags: java, android

Meu *app* pega uma imagem da galeria ou tira uma foto, como pegar essa imagem e converter para *base64*?

```
  private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bytes);
    System.out.println(data);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    FileOutputStream fo;

    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ivImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap bm=null;

    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta criar um vetor de *bytes* para receber o `ByteArrayOutputStream` usando o método `toByteArray` convertendo *bytes* para um vetor de *bytes*. Logo depois importe a *lib* [`android.util.Base64`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html), crie uma *string* para receber o `Base64` convertendo para string através do método `encodeToString`. Veja um exemplo:

```
byte[] b = bytes.toByteArray();
String encodedfile = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente ! Obrigado !